# Android Firmware 4.4.2 Bluetooth keep disconnecting

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a problem in Android Bluetooth connection. I have a bluetooth device connected to the phone. The device will send data to the phone every 10 seconds.

**Android Firmware version below 4.4.2** has no problem in sending data and bluetooth connection. 
**Android Firmware version above 4.4.2** keep disconnecting every 10 seconds or more. Is this the Android problem or my programming problem ?

Comment: We can only find out if it is your programming problem when you post the most essential parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Below my programming code. When i tested on Android phone firmware version 4.4.2 and above it keep receiving ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED. Android phone firmware version below 4.4.2 working perfectly fine.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
String action = intent.getAction();

if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) 
{
Log.d("MainActivity","Bluetooth connected.");
}
else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) 
{
Log.d("MainActivity","Bluetooth disconnected.");    
}else{
Toast.makeText(context, action, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
};
```